# tldScanJar warning using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I receive a tldScanJar warning using Tomcat. The console of eclipse shows:

> org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar warning: Failed to
>   process JAR
>   [jar:jndi:/localhost/fileUpload/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar!/null]
>   for TLD files java.io.IOException: access denied

Any suggestion is welcome

Answer (score 3):

Had this yesterday myself on tomcat 7.0.12, jdk 1.6.0_25 (x64, centos).  Turned out to be that removal of the temp directory from the tomcat directory caused this issue.  Try adding tomcat/temp and ensuring that the user running tomcat has full control of it.  Also, check permissions to the rest of the tomcat directory to be sure that it isn't having an access problem there, either.

Comment: the tomcat/temp directory is there, and my os is windows 7. Now i found that all the jar i put on the web-inf/lib will cause this waring, it really confuse me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, setting "Full" permissions for my user account (`RMB on Tomcat dir -> Security -> Edit -> Add, write your login -> Ok, and check "Full control"`).

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error with Tomcat 7.0.21 on Windows 7 when a war contained jars which had duplicate class definitions (a class was defined in more than 1 jar within the war's `WEB-INF/lib` directory).  Cleaning up the jar list solved the problem (tho i didn't go back and try to repro/test it).

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, I was getting the same issue, but I was doing one mistake, I had opened my IDE (I was using `IntelliJ`) by simply double clicked.

But when I opend my IDE with right-click, and choose *Run as Adminstrator* then it does not happened in my case. So try it. Please don't ignore any small mistake.